# Two itunes accounts on one laptop

Tags: itunes

My wife and I have two separate iTunes accounts and two separate laptops.  Now that we are married, when it came to the time we both needed to replace our own laptops we decided just to buy one.  I would be grateful for any advice on what the best way would be to deal with our separate iTunes accounts.  Can we merge them, or both have our own iTunes accounts installed on the same machine.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The accounts cannot be merged, which makes Mark's existing answer the only real option - but I just wanted to add that your can share apps, books, music etc, rather than merge, by using [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)

Answer (score 2):

You should each have your own user account/login on the computer then you can have each use your own iTunes, iCloud, email, Facebook, Twitter, etc… accounts.

You can create an user account on your computer by going to

1. System Preferences > Users & Groups,
2. Unlock that panel if necessary (Click on the lock in the lower left corner and enter you password if the lock icon shows as locked)
3. Then press the "+" icon in the table above the unlocked icon to add another account to your computer.

Comment: To add to Mark's answer...   you might find this article helpful.   It gives a good tutorial on adding multiple user accounts to the system, and how to configure them.    http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-multiple-user-accounts-on-os-x/